# Preserve space xml and xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a problem with space preserving. I have xml file where ex.:

```
<element>     value of element    <element>
```

and I have to preserve all the spaces during xsl transformation. The value of element need to starts after few spaces...Is there any way to do this?
I tried:

```
xml:preserve-space = "true"

disable-output-escaping="yes"
```

None of this worked in this case. 
Here is example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE element [
<!ATTLIST content xml:space (default|preserve) "preserve">
]>

<element xml:space='preserve'>
<content>          some         content       </content>
</element>
```

I need all those spaces to stay

Comment: Try to add : `<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>`

Comment: I tried this, no effect

Comment: Can you create a *small but complete* example that we can run -possibly [here](http://xsltransform.net/)- and see the problem?

Comment: Show us your code that handles that element, together with the `xsl:output` method you have as we need to know whether the transformation result is plain text or HTML or some other XML format.

Comment: You say you have a problem with space preserving, but you don't say what the problem is. What are you doing, what effect is it having, and how does the output differ from what you would expect.

Comment: The problem is that i have a value of element which look like: "spacespacespaceVALUEspacespacespace" I would like all those spaces to stay, but even when I start xml file in the browser all spacec dissapear

Answer (score 1):

> *but even when I start xml file in the browser all spacec dissapear*

This was your last comment, but the question didn't say anything about browsers. Spaces in browsers probably means you are using the XML to load as (X)HTML in browsers. In (X)HTML, spaces are usually ignored. However, you can [fix this with CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

```
/* you probably want to replace * with an actual element name */
* {
    white-space: preserve
}
```

Another way to fix this is by replacing the spaces with a [NON-BREAKING-SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), for instance:

```xml
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '&#160;')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But, as others have already commented, you have not shown the actual input XML, actual XSLT or the actual (incorrect) output XML, so I am unsure whether this will actually help you. If you still need further help, I kindly suggest you update your question (click the Edit button) with the relevant information.

Comment: @J.B., good, thanks. But you didn't answer the questions. The code I show above will preserve spaces, or, if you want to show them in HTML, will force them to be translated. If still not what you want, update your question with the wanted output and with what you have done but doesn't work. Please read [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: @J.B. PS: be very aware that viewing XML or HTML in browsers will usually **not display the spaces**. This is a browser thing. That's why I gave you the hint to transform them to nbsp's.